# Can the Java Restlet API Work Be Used With REST PHP APIs?

Tags: java, php, rest, networking

Would you be able to use the Java Restlet RESTful API to interface with some provider's API that is written in PHP?

If so, by what means is this done?

More specifically, for anyone who has used the Restlet API, do you know of any particular packages or classes intended for this use?

Comment: I think your question (as currently written) is [too broad for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  What research have you done? What have you tried and where have you stumbled?

Comment: I've researched RESTful design aspects and Java-implementations.  I don't really think it's broad so much as just simple.  It doesn't require an in-depth answer, just an example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTfull web services are designed to be language independent. Most people use JSON as way of communication with REST. And this makes the whole thing language independent.

There is no reason why your Java RESTful API shouldnot work with PHP REST API.

Comment: Ok.  How does it work though?  Does the language API have methods to invoke code in the PHP API?

Comment: RESTfull webservices work on url. Each service is mapped to a specific url and method(GET,PUT,POST etc). You can call the services using rest clients.

Comment: Right.  So calling the service with a GET request will just run whatever method is mapped to GET regardless of the language?